# trimming the right eight characters in date column

Tags: t-sql

```
SELECT Name,[Document Name], convert(datetime,[DEPARTURE] ,103) as DTA  ,convert(datetime,[ARRIVAL],103 ) AS TIMO
INTO TEMP
from Timeless
SELECT DISTINCT[DOCUMENT NAME],NAME, (MAX (DTA)-MIN(TIMO)) AS HORO
FROM TEMP 
GROUP BY [DOCUMENT NAME],NAME
DROP TABLE TEMP
```

This is the script and the output i am getting is

```
DOCUMENT NAME              NAME      HORO
BH 1704031143460533600198   BH  0 12:05AM
```

Getting the horo in this format is not right or not what I want 
kindly help

Comment: This will show you how to get all the different date/time formats in tsql: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

*IF* you are looking to determine a time span between the min and max date, I would use the [DateDiff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql) function.